# How to modify a .sty file?

Tags: packages, patching

I am trying to modify the `fontawesome.sty` file. I just include the command in the style file and it works but without showing the Skype icon just showing an empty box.

```
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@icon-skype\endcsname         {\symbol{"F17E}}  \def\faSkype             {{\FA\csname faicon@icon-skype\endcsname}}
```

Comment: Do not change a style file, it will be lost with the next update. You can put the command in your preamble or contact the maintainer of the package, he might add it.

Comment: @Johannes_B but last time 2013/05/10 v 3.1.1 was update and I also contact with xdanaux through but still no response. So now I'm try to make my fontawesome. sty file.

Comment: I just had a look into the otf. Possible that the sign doesn't even exist in the font? So all your efforts point to an empty point.

Comment: Going to the development page on [github](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) you can download the new version containing the symbol. Adding you line to the preamble (enclosed in `makeatletter` and `makeatother`) works just fine. Be sure that TeX can find the font.

Comment: @Johannes_B http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/. But it's not working I try it.

Comment: What is not working? Compiling `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@icon-skype\endcsname         {\symbol{"F17E}}  \def\faSkype             {{\FA\csname faicon@icon-skype\endcsname}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 \faSkype
\end{document}
` with the font file `FontAwesome.otf` in the same folder, it works perfectly fine. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Johannes_B which editor are you using. I am using the WinEdt.

Answer (score 6):

Modifying the style file is not recommended since an update will reset your modification. The `xpatch` package is used for this. So, instead, you can add the following lines to the preamble of your .tex file (without touching the .sty file):

```
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\xpatchcmd{<\command>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

See the `xpatch` package [here](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xpatch/xpatch.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Isn't the OP trying to add an additional command, though? (Note that I'm not sure about this but that's what seems to be happening from the comments.)

Comment: @cfr I wonder how this could get that manny upvotes, since it doesn't answer what the OP wants. It answers the titlequestion, tough.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- i think you've identified the "why": the answer addresses the title question.  not all titles accurately represent the actual question, and as you observe, this is one of those.  on the other hand, the point made in the answer is *very* important, and a useful workaround is provided, so for that reason, it got an upvote from me.